# Libgdx enemy moving

Tags: android, artificial-intelligence, libgdx

I have question about moving enemy on my game like turtles in Mario brother game.

I'm working on platformer game like mario brother game in libgdx. I make the ground, player moving on ground, game decorations etc... but I don't know how to make enemy moving.

When should enemy start moving(rendering)? on some time delay or when player is close to enemy (1-2 screens in width), all the time ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lets say you have something like this image:

[image]

When you move your character, the visible area moves with it, so that your character is for example always in the middle.

When the character moves, `charX` increases and after he travels a certain distance he gets to a position when the enemy activates:

[image]

And it stays active until character gets here:

[image]

The implementation could be something like this:
`someOffset` can be an arbitrary constant value, you use it so that the enemy activates before it enters the screen and becomes visible.

So, for each frame you could do this:

```
if (Math.abs(enemyX - charX) <= visibleWidth / 2 + someOffset) {
    // the enemy patrols between leftLimit and rightLimit
    if (enemySpeed < 0 && enemyX < leftLimit) {
        enemyX = leftLimit;
        enemySpeed = -enemySpeed;
    } else if (enemySpeed > 0 && enemyX > rightLimit) {
        enemyX = rightLimit;
        enemySpeed = -enemySpeed;
    }

    enemyX += enemySpeed * delta;

    renderEnemy();
}
```

**[Update]**

If I remember correctly, the screen in Mario can only go to the right. If Mario goes to the left, the screen stays in position, and allows Mario only to get to its left edge, no further.

Since he is not always in the same position on the visible area, it might be better to have enemies be active/rendered based on visible area position instead of character position.

Lets say that `visibleX` is the x-position of the left edge of visible area (green rectangle).

On each update you could do something like:

```
visibleX = Math.max(charX - visibleWidth / 2, visibleX);

if (enemyX <= visibleX + visibleWidth + someOffset && enemyX >= visibleX - someOffset) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I know I'm not suppose to post that, but your answer is really well structured, well edited and well imaged! Very good job @mrzli !!!